# How can I find a program name so I can open them?

Tags: debian, command-line, terminal

I'm a new user in Linux, and I want to know how can I find a name of an installed program so I can open it from the terminal.
Is there a way?

For example, I use the system on Portuguese language, and the default image viewer is called "Visualizador de Imagem", and that doesn't work on the Terminal, neither "image-viewer". So, I want to, execute the program and see the name of the process, so I can call it another time direct from the terminal.

Comment: If the application is on a menu you can right click on the menu item to get the 'properties'. (You may have to add the item to a panel first to expose the properties)  One of the properties will give you the path to the command.

Comment: This is only a partial solution but you can list **most** of the executables in a package by running `dpkg -L packagename` and piping into `grep bin/`.  e.g. `dpkg -L dpkg | grep bin/` (note that some packages have some executables under /usr/share or /usr/lib, so won't be listed with a simple grep like that). You can also list a package's man pages with `grep man/`.   Or if you have my `dlocate` package installed, you can use `dlocate --lsbin dpkg` or `dlocate --lsman dpkg` (dlocate uses a more accurate method involving `stat` to find executables in a package)

Answer (score 1):

type `xprop` (piping with `grep WM_CLASS` should give you faster what you want) on your terminal and hit enter. your mouse pointer should change, then click on the program